# Rails processing as JS when nromally it processes as HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the process of writing a text field as a static SVG file, for some reason, adding the following code to a controller action

```
    @markeradhoc_new = Markeradhoc.create(text: params[:content][:characters], colour_text: @marker_text_colour, svg: adhoc_svg)
    @target = 'public/' + params[:content][:characters] + '.svg'

    f = File.new(@target, "w")
    f.write(@markeradhoc_new.svg)
    f.close
```

makes rails process the action  as JS  `Processing by ContentsController#update as JS`  when without the block regarding `f` it processes as expected in HTML

Why is Rails bouncing to a different rendering mechanism?  Could this also explain why the file is not being written?

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - public/cS.svg):
```

Comment: This might happening because you are making a XHR request. You can explicitly define your output / redirection by check if the request.xhr? Is true.